# After a few days, my Macbook's connection to the PC will go bad, how to solve it?

Tags: sharing, home-sharing

I use `smb` to connect to the PC to look at the files:

In Finder,  Go -> Connect to Server

and I use

```
smb://mypc      <-- this is my pc's name in the config
```

to be able to look at the shared folders on my PC from the macbook (wireless).  But after a couple of day or sometimes a few days, the connection goes bad, and reconnect is waiting for 10 minutes and it still tries to connect.

Is there a way around this?  Using a different method?  For example, if I set up a webserver on my PC, then the files can be more easily accessible because the macbook has no problem accessing any websites, but i just don't want to need to set up a webserver to do file access.

Comment: What about FTP? But again you'll need third-party server/client

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess; does you home network use DHCP? I wonder if the address lease is timing out and the Mac isn't looking for the PC via your DNS.

You could try changing the address lease time on your router to never expire (depending on router type), or you might consider giving the PC a fixed address instead of using DHCP.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer so much as a strategy, I find that sometimes going to a "Recent Folder" ( Finder → Go → Recent Folder → *some folder name*) where *some folder name* is on the smb share works instantly.